# How do I come back after falling behind in levels?

Tags: dota-2

Over the last few days, I have had games, where I fall behind in Hero levels, due to teammates playing badly and feeding the enemy heroes.
This outcome makes it difficult to get back into the game.

**What is the best way to deal with such a situation, in regard to get make your Hero able to stand up to the enemy heroes?**

*EDIT: I usually play a Nuker, such as Lion.*

Comment: This is a really broad question, can you elaborate on the types of heroes/roles you play when you notice you are falling behind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First and foremost, always try to be aware of the times that you're not getting exp.  You need to be within 1300 range of a dying creep to get the experience, which is about the same distance as a pudge hook or a blink dagger range. Play a few games with the sole target of getting as much exp as possible, so not wandering between lanes too much - use scrolls, and make the most of every creep wave.

If you're playing mid - make sure that you push the wave into the enemy tower before looking for runes, this forces the enemy to defend or lose 3-4 creeps of exp while you have time to pick up a rune without losing any.  If you check for a rune (or worse, go back to base) and are missing exp on the mid lane you're putting yourself in a huge disadvantage.  On those level based heroes it is critical that you get as much exp as possible.
Learn to mind game your opponent in terms of last hitting, to put them off when they try to deny (or better harass them off the lane).

If you're playing a safe lane supportive role, make sure that any creep pulls you do are double stacks, or pull throughs to a 2nd camp - not just single stacks.  Single stacks cause the lanes to push to the enemy tower, meaning you have to hang further back from the creep wave to not risk your life, and this makes it much easier for the enemy to zone you out of the experience range.

Always carry a tp scroll from as early as possible - teleporting between lanes rather than walking is 100% worth it if you are missing out on a lot of XP.  Ideally, teleport in when the enemy tries to gank one of your lanes, and use your burst damage potential to turn the ganks around - this will give you huge boosts in xp.

Also needless to say, avoid deaths as much as possible. Learn all the best ward spots and keep as good map coverage.  The best way to not get ganked is to not be there - and ideally make your enemy waste time rotating between lanes as well.

Hope these general comments are of some use to you, if you want to post a replay ID or two, I'd be happy to give more specific advice.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. You mentioned creep pulls should be double stacked. Are you refering to the creeps in the jungles?

Comment: Yeah, if you're playing lane support, it is common to pull the neutrals into your wave of creeps when the lane is pushed towards the enemy tower, doing this pulls the lane equilibrium back to a safer place for your carry to farm, and denies exp from the enemy.  See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-TzwBr69cuI for an example.

Answer (score 3):

If the other team is destroying you there are really two options to come back:

### Team Fights:

Group up with your team, no matter how crappy they are you should still be able to surprise and kill a couple enemy heroes that are alone.  Ways to do this could be warding spots they go to alone (jungles) or just catching them in a lane.

This obviously won't work if they're together and stronger than you.

### Jungling:

Your team sucking and not doing anything?  Just jungle excess time away.  Be sure to ward or else the other team will just kill you.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on your team composition and that of the opponents, but here's a couple of points that apply pretty often...

If it's still early in the game i.e. during the laning stage, the best way would be to get a couple of teammates organized and set up a gank or two, making sure to only proceed if the numbers are clearly in your favor. Remember that kills tend to reward more and more as the game goes, so a couple of successful kills at around 10:00 minutes or so can easily make up for a lot more than that if they happened early.

If it's getting later into the game, you have to try to make the opponents pay when they try to break your base by making sure to be grouped up on the high ground and ideally having at least a few buybacks. Transitioning from a successful laning/ganking stage to breaking the base is something that can be very difficult against a turtled lineup on the high ground with buybacks, even to a team that has been up to that point stomping. They have to do it at some point, and, especially for unorganized pubs, it can so easily completely turn on them, leading to wipes going the other way, which again matters because kills tend to yield more rewards as the game goes on.

Answer (score 0):

Win your lane, then gank your ally's lane. With a nuker like Lion or Lina if you fall behind in levels and farm you're limited to a less than useful role, so I'd suggest playing more aggressively in your lane so that you don't fall too behind without at least forcing an enemy hero or two to be behind as well. If you pick up Lion and don't get early kills, the hero falls off very quickly and hits mana and cooldown issues. He needs level 11 badly so that he can stay relevant in midgame.